# How to make a chained fetch and show results as each step becomes available?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, svelte

I'm fetching article list data from API and use/fetch Unsplash API to get relative images according to each fetched article title.

This is my code:

```
let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';

async function getData(url) {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const objects = await res.json();

    await Promise.all(objects.map(async (object) => {
        const res = await fetch('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=XXX&content_filter=high&per_page=1&query=' + object.title);
        const image = await res.json();
        object.image_url = image.results[0].urls.small
        object.image_alt = image.results[0].alt_description
    }));
}

let articles_1 = getData(url + '/articles/index/1/');
let articles_2 = getData(url + '/articles/index/2/');
let articles_3 = getData(url + '/articles/index/3/');
```

I am showing three different categories at once on the same page. That's why I call that function three times.

Question:

When this function kicks, results are shown after both article data and images are fetched. But I want to show article data first when it's been fetched and then images when they get fetched in order to shorten the user waiting time. How can I achieve it wether with Svelte reactive declaration or plain Javascript?

Comment: Try using some asynchronous action with `.then` after fetching! You can read more about fetching along with reacting after fetching here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch, along with `.then` here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: Thanks for the links but I didn't accomplish it again. And I didn't get; is there anything that `.then` can do but not `await`?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no. However, `.then` continues a chain of async functions, whereas await can be used to 'split' it apart. I posted my best attempt at solving your problem, however, I couldn't test it because your example does not have a minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to seperate the two functions, so they can be called in sequence.

```
const endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';

const getArticles = async (url) => {
    return fetch(url).res.json();
};
const renderArticles = async (articles) => {
    // render article set and return it as a DOM object
    return articlesDOM;
};

const getImageForArticle = async (articleNode) => {
    const res = await = fetch('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=XXX&content_filter=high&per_page=1&query=' + object.title);
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = res.results[0].urls.small;
    img.alt = res.results[0].alt_description;
    return {img, articleNode};
};
const renderImage = async (stuff) => {
    const {img, articleNode} = stuff;
    // inject your img into your article
};

// now call in sequence

getArticles(endpoint+'/articles/index/1/').then(renderArticles).then(articleNodes => {
    const promises = articleNodes.map(articleNode => {
        return getImageForArticle(articleNode).then(renderImage);
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do (I don't have a minimal working example), here's my best attempt at it:

```
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';

async function getData(url) {
  var data = fetch(url)
    .then(data => data.json())
  
  await data.then(data => ArticleFunc(data))
  
  await data.then(function(data) {
      data.map(function(object) {
        fetch('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=XXX&content_filter=high&per_page=1&query=' + object.title)
          .then(data => data.json())
        object.image_url = image.results[0].urls.small
        object.image_alt = image.results[0].alt_description
        ImageFunc(object)
      })
    })
}

function ArticleFunc(data){
  //display article
}

function ImageFunc(data){
  //display image
}

getData(url + '/articles/index/1/');
getData(url + '/articles/index/2/');
getData(url + '/articles/index/3/');
```

Note that this is to be treated as pseudocode, as again, it is untested due to the absense of a minimal working example.